# UVM- How to get config object from config db to the tb_top

Tags: uvm

I have some forces (interface to dut) in my tb_top file.

For example:

```
      // rx forces and assignments
   assign rx_vif.chind2 = dut.rx_fe.chind2;
      initial begin
                force dut.rx_fe.x = rx_vif.x;
      end
   end
```

I want to execute above only if the rx_agent is active.

For this I have to  get the rx_agent_config object to the tb_top like this:

```
  if(!uvm_config_db #(rx_agent_config)::get(this, "", "db_rx_agent_config", m_rx_cfg)) begin
            `uvm_error("top", "rx_agent_config not found")
  end//if
```

THhe code for set:

```
 uvm_config_db #(rx_agent_config)::set(this, "*", "db_rx_agent_config", m_cfg.m_rx_agent_cfg);
```

What should I write instead of this (in the get function)?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/19840611/best-way-to-access-the-uvm-config-db-from-the-testbench/19882169#19882169

Comment: @nguthrie I tried it but I got error when I run It. UVM_ERROR ../sv/girobo2_tb_top.sv(175) @ 0: reporter [top] rx_agent_config not found

Comment: You probably need to include your environment code in a package and then import it into your tb_top

Comment: @nguthrie - it's alsraedy imported.

Comment: where have you set the config object?

Comment: @Karan Shah - I set it in the env

Comment: Can you please put that code here as well?

Comment: @Karan Shah -  edited.

Comment: In the set code, also you have written `get` method.

Comment: @Karan Shah - edited (it was a mistake).

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/129389/discussion-between-karan-shah-and-sara8d).

Answer (score 0):

Supposed that your component name is "comp" in ENV, and the env is named "env" in the uvm_test, so in test bench top module, you should     use below code to get the configuration handle

```
uvm_config_db#(rx_agent_cfg)::get(null, "uvm_test_top.env.comp", "db_rx_agent_cfg", rx_cfg);
```

Because the earliest time you could set "rx_agent_cfg" in the uvm_config_db is 0 time in build_phase, so it is safe to do get after a #0 delay in the initial block.